# Windows 10 - language, keyboard, display, units - confussion

Tags: windows-10, language

I used to master this in windows 8.1 and i believe nothing has changed that much, i just messed up at setup and now I'm completely lost. So, what do i want: windows to be entirely in English. Start menu, settings, everything displayed in English language. However, i want keyboard layout in different language, which also effects formats (date style etc.).

If someone knows how to do this properly I'd appreciate a step by step guide. I installed a bunch of stuff i probably don't need, so tell me please where to set up what. Thank you a bunch!